# " Unfortunately, CloudAgent has stopped"

Tags: applications

When viewing images in the Gallery, the message "Unfortunately, CloudAgent has stopped". Then the screen goes black.  How can I fix this?

I have a Samsung Galaxy Pro 8.4 tablet, model SM-T320. The Android version is 4.4.2. This just started today.

Comment: I found the answer to this on another Android site. Just open the Dropbox app and sign out. This fixed the problem for me. You can then sign back in to Dropbox.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it.  You can post that as an answer below so other can see that this has been solved and vote it up.

Answer (score 1):

### To Log Out of Dropbox

1. While in the Dropbox application, tap on the Menue Bar (the 3-horizonal bars icon located at the upper left-hand corner).
2. After the Menue List populates the screen, tap the Gear icon (Dropbox settings) located at the upper right-hand corner.
3. When the Dropbox settings window populates, tap on the list item "Sign out of Dropbox" which is approximately the fifth item down on the list.

This will log you out of the Dropbox phone application.